# Within SSIS - Is it possible to deploy one package multiple times in the same instance and set different ConfigFilters (I'm using SQL for config)

Tags: sql-server-2005, configuration, ssis

In my environment my Dev and QA Database Instances are on the same server.  I would like to deploy the same package (or different versions of the package) into SSIS and set the filter to select different rows in the Config table.  Is this possible? This is SQL 2005.

For the sake of this question lets say I have one variable, which is a directory path. I would like to have these variables in the table twice (with different Filters applied (Dev and QA) as below (simplified) . . .

Filter / Variable Value / Variable Name
Dev / c:\data\dev / FilePath
QA / c:\data\qa / FilePath

Do I need to apply a change within the settings of the package in SSIS or is it changed on the job step within Agent?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SSIS/69739/

Comment: While this is an alternative it does not address my original question.  Our corporate direction is to utilize the config in the database and I am looking for a way to change the filter for a package at run time.